# Is it possible to restrict access to a page based on a visitor's country?

Tags: security

Is it possible to restrict access to a page based on a visitor's country?

For instance, only users in the US can view the FAQ page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Luke Holder has created a plugin that would help you in this situation.

[Geo Plugin for Craft CMS](https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-geo)

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old post, but it's something we've tackled recently and wanted to put out our solution.

If you're using CloudFlare you could use our [Country Detect](https://github.com/madebymutual/Country-Detect) plugin, otherwise as John Moylan mentioned [Luke Holder's Geo Plugin](https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-geo) can achieve the same thing. The only advantage of our plugin is that it saves a bit of processing if you're already using CloudFlare.

You could then conditionally show content to US folks only at by something like this...

```
{% if craft.countryDetect.country == "US" %}
    {# Put your FAQs for USA here #}
{% elseif %}
    {# Content or redirect() goes here #}
{% endif %}
```